# Assigning Java array to non array attribute - Serilizable

Tags: java, arrays

Why first line of following method compiles while second not? I would expect both fail.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ArrayConversions {
    Serializable serial = new Serializable[5];
    Runnable run = new Runnable[5];
}
```

Comment: change it to array `Runnable[] run = new Runnable[5];`

Comment: @Braj The question is why the first one does not fail, not why the second one does fail.

Comment: @Thirler I have already posted an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line compiles because all arrays implement `Serializable`. From the [JLS section 10.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8):

> Although an array type is not a class, the Class object of every array acts as if:
>
> - The direct superclass of every array type is Object.
> - Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.

So you could use:

```
Serializable serial = new int[10];
```

You *happen* to have created a `Serializable[]`, but that's just a coincidence - it's not like you're *meant* to be able to assign an array type value to its element type value.

So your mistake can be seen for `Object` as well:

```
Object o = new Object[10]; // Or new String[10] or new int[10] or whatever
```

... but these are just about what array types support.

Answer (score 0):

array is `Serializable` that why its fine to say

```
Serializable serial = new Serializable[5];
```

Comment: This is a bit opaque, especially as to new programmers it may appear a tautology.  Perhaps a demonstration is in order?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Jon Skeet has already has described it. So I don't need to explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

The second one should be obvious. We would expect `Runnable[] run...`. The first one is not that obvious. It is because an array of Serializable does implement the Serializable interface - in a hidden way. So an array can be considered as a `Serializable` object.